# Using electron-progressbar in renderer process

Tags: javascript, electron

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-progressbar#more-examples

Hi, I need to use progressbar in electron.

But with the progressbar package, It turned out that examples can be used in main process not in renderer process.

Is it possible to use that in renderer process so that the user clicks the calculation button and waits for a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

#### 1. In the main process

```
global.ProgressBar = require('electron-progressbar');
```

#### 2. In the renderer process

```
const { getGlobal, app } = require('electron').remote;
const ProgressBar = getGlobal('ProgressBar');

app.on('ready', function() {
  var progressBar = new ProgressBar({
  text: 'Preparing data...',
  detail: 'Wait...'
});
```

Comment: For me this error happens do you know why??

Uncaught TypeError: ProgressBar is not a constructor

Comment: @AntonioSEO check the edited answer. There was a correction. I believe now it should work fine.